# Get the actual status of the print from the network PC

Tags: printing, raspberrypi

Our job is to directly access the printer using Raspberry Pi. But as it was not a straight forward, we added the network server in the system and now we are successfully able to give the print from Raspberry Pi to network PC and network PC communicates with actual printer and gets a printout.

We use CUPS drivers on the RPi (Raspberry Pi). Now we want to know the status of the print on the RPi.

We observed that once the print command initiated from RPi, the job is removed from the RPi and it is available in the queue of network PC. So, the actual status of the print cannot be available on the RPi.

Is there any way on RPi, we can get the actual status of the print job is successful or wait or failed?